# There should be an option to mark favourite any user's profile

Tags: feature-request

I often see the users having strong profile. I can get a lot of info and knowledge from their profile. I wish to read the answers and questions of that user. But there is no option in StackExchange to save / mark favourite that profile.

I think, It should be there

Comment: Been asked in various forms before and the answer is always the same - Stack Overflow is not a social media site so tracking users is not really something that most users want.

Answer (score 4):

This feature does not exist on Stack Overflow or at all on the Stack Exchange network because it is not a social networking site. The actual user who posted the content is not as important than the content itself. You could be "following" a user who is fantastic at python but has zero experience with jQuery. One should always consider the content and not rely only on the fact that it was posted by a high rep user.

That being said, you can add a user's RSS feed to your favorite RSS reader.

[image] (Click to enlarge)

This icon appears on the bottom right corner of the users profile page.

Within this RSS feed you'll be able to monitor the users actions on the site, new questions, answers, comments, etc.

Comment: Well hidden features for the win!

Comment: @mus - maybe the updated screenshot will help with that :P

Comment: Also note you can search by user id: `user:593627` will show my questions and answers. Find out a user's id by looking in the url on their profile page. The search box also has this pre-populated.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use your browser's bookmark feature.

The reason it exists for questions is so that you can be notified when a new answer/edit/... has been posted on the question. It doesn't really make sense to get a notification for every action of a user you'd like to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree it is nice to have a good quality content source to look back at, I don't see how it would be of any benefit to review posts based on who the user is. Why would you want to look through a collection of posts that might not even relate to a subject you care about? Just knowing that the user generally posts good content doesn't really mean they will be posting content you are interested in, or have any use for.

I think the ability to favorite questions is already more than enough. This means you can always keep track of good quality, **relevant** posts.

If you care enough about the good users, then most of them will likely have their own blogs. Find out the urls for them (most of the well known users usually add a link to their profile) and you can favorite them with your browser and keep up to date with their posts that way.